# How to work with a nondeterministic number of jQuery promises?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

If I have a nondeterministic number of promises being generated how do I handle them as a group to ensure the all of the promises in the group have been resolved before I move forward in my code?

I though about using `jQuery.when` but it looks like it requires a deterministic number of promises passed as arguments. I thought I would be able to pass an array of promises for processing but based upon the docs I think it will evaluate this array as a single resolved promise.

Comment: A composite promise could be made, with a queue of dependent promises .. but I don't know of anything standard.

Comment: I think you could create a function that looped over the promises and passed them to `jQuery.when` just as if you had passed them manually one at a time.

Comment: "Nondeterministic"? I think you mean "indeterminate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

push all the promises into an array and use:

```
$.when.apply(null, promiseArray).done(function() {....
```